# found scala.Int(0) required Int 0

Tags: scala

I am new to scala, and I am running some exercises from book about to implement a List.

I have a method `sum` to add all numbers in list. I use TDD approach, so first I just return 0 to make it fail. But the compile complains that type mismatch. It expects `Int` but received a `scala.Int`.

```
def sum[Int](as: MList[Int]): Int = 
{
    0
}
```

Complain messages:

```
MList.scala:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.Int(0)
 required: Int
    0
    ^
one error found
```

So I try to changed to

```
def sum[scala.Int](as: MList[scala.Int]): scala.Int = 
{
    0
}
```

Compiler complains that `.` should not exist in `[scala.Int]`.

I also tried cast 0 to `new Int(0)`, `Int(0)`, `(Int)0`, `new Int` (I come from C++) to match the return type, and it didn't work too.

What's difference between `scala.Int(0)` and a literal `0`? Is that I forget to include some package like built-in number package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that, here

```
def sum[Int](as: MList[Int]): Int = 0
       ^^^^^
```

You're declaring a new type called `Int` that shadows `scala.Int`.
Your `sum` method is generic, and `Int` is the name of its type parameter.

Just remove the type parameter.

```
def sum(as: MList[Int]): Int = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. 
Because the previous method I implemented is `def apply[A](as: A*): MList[A] = {...}`, I just replace the A with Int. Haha