# Scala function error: type mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, iterator

I need to calculate new column while processing data using Spark.
Below code works fine

```
scala> def f[Int](iter: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[(Int, Int)] = {
     |   var res = List[(Int, Int)]()
     |   while (iter.hasNext)
     |   {
     |     val x = iter.next;
     |     res = res ::: List((x, x))
     |   }
     |   res.iterator
     | }
f: [Int](iter: Iterator[Int])Iterator[(Int, Int)]

scala> sc.parallelize(Iterator(1,1,2,5,1,3).toSeq).mapPartitions(f).collect
res34: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (1,1), (2,2), (5,5), (1,1), (3,3))
```

Second value of each element should be calculated using some complex logic and defining of function fails when I try to use variable or even constant.

```
scala> def f[Int](iter: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[(Int, Int)] = {
     |   var res = List[(Int, Int)]()
     |   var y = 1
     |   while (iter.hasNext)
     |   {
     |     val x = iter.next;
     |     res = res ::: List((x, y)) // List((x, 1))
     |   }
     |   res.iterator
     | }
<console>:39: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(Int, Any)]
 required: List[(Int, Int)]
           res = res ::: List((x, y)) // List((x, 1))
```

Why does it fail and how to fix?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete `[Int]` from signature.

It tells compiler, that "Int" in the scope of the function is a type argument, so it can be any type - Int, String.

When you do `var y = 1`, Scala infers type scala.Int, but in your function Int if used as type argument and List is a list of tuples of this type argument, not Scala.Int.

Those two will work:

```
def f[E](iter: Iterator[E]) : Iterator[(E, Int)] = {
    var res = List[(E, Int)]()
    var y = 1
    while (iter.hasNext)
    {
      val x = iter.next;
      res = res ::: List((x, y)) // List((x, 1))
    }
    res.iterator
  }
```

and

```
def f(iter: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[(Int, Int)] = {
    var res = List[(Int, Int)]()
    var y = 1
    while (iter.hasNext)
    {
      val x = iter.next;
      res = res ::: List((x, y)) // List((x, 1))
    }
    res.iterator
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a bit more details for other who may have this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142402/found-scala-int0-required-int-0.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what line 39 is but why recoding map function to add a 1?

You can just do :

```
val x = List(1,2,3,4,5).iterator
val y = x.map((_,1))

print(y.mkString(" "))

(1,1) (2,1) (3,1) (4,1) (5,1)
```

Comment: `Second value of each element should be calculated using some complex logic` so one is just an example :)

Comment: OK but you can still use the map function instead of recoding an iterator (which is creating a big in memory list and convert it back to iterator). You code may fail if iter is too big.

Comment: Yes and not. We don't know exactly what author needs, maybe this function is just a very simple example - Minimal Reproduction. She / he will choose what's better :)

Comment: I know probably. She or he wants to use it inside `mapPartitions`, there you must use an Iterator

Comment: T. Gawęda - exactly! Benjamin, I intentionally put mapPartitions into code snippet. Sorry to see that it was not clear enough.